# Too much pressure causes phone to beep?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, sound, developer-preview, touch

Sometimes I fall asleep with my Lumia 950 XL in hand and if I happen to roll on top of it, the phone beeps me awake. (This only ever happened twice.) It uses a completely unique audio cue, lower (that is to say; deeper) and shorter than normal notification chimes. A single tone. Does not repeat or get louder, but nor does it respect volume sliders/quiet hours settings, interestingly enough.

Very similar behavior to what old keyboards/computers did when we held down a lot of keys at once. Except the sound -- that was a constant high pitched "beep - beep - beep..." and this is a single dialtone-like "bap" and very short.

This undocumented feature is really useful as I don't want to crack my screen or break my phone in half by sleeping on top of it carelessly. Can anyone even reproduce this strange behavior? Is it configurable? Or am I hallucinating? No matter how much I press the phone with my palm, it does not beep. Only when I fall asleep on it.

Bonus afterthought: not sure if the screen timing out by itself matters or not.

((Creating the new tags 'sensors undocumented sleep' requires at least 150 reputation.))

Comment: Does the phone show any notifications? Does the screen turn on when it beeps? Are you pressing any of the buttons, perhaps? Do you have any Bluetooth accessories paired? Could you be activating Cortana's speech detection? (You can check the latter by opening Cortana and touching the microphone icon, or by long-pressing on the search icon at the bottom of the screen).

Comment: None of those I'm afraid. Notifications list is empty, screen remains off, buttons are hard to press so not likely, bluetooth is off, cortana speech recognition start has a different, higher pitched and longer "happy" chime.